# Rails render html source from variable on javascript view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, escaping

I need to change html of a div to the value of a string of an object

```
string
 > "\n<div>\n\t<div>\n\t\t<a id='dog'>cat</a>\n\t</div>\n</div>\n\n\t"

string.inspect
 > "\"\\n<div>\\n\\t<div>\\n\\t\\t<a id='dog'>cat</a>\\n\\t</div>\\n</div>\\n\\n\\t\""
```

I've tried

```
$(div).html("<%= render(partial: '_html') ");
```

where _html is just

```
 <%= @html %>
```

I've tried with j, raw, h, html_safe, setting @html as string.inspect, eval(@html.inspect), ...

But none of these ways have helped.

Goal is to put exactly "string" into the javascript source with no changes in escaping nor extra quotes added.

How can I do it?

Comment: I think you might just need to wrap it in quotes, e.g. `$(div).html("<%= raw render(partial: '_html') %>" ` ... can you check the output of the HTML in the browser and see what's wrong? Also note, you shouldn't use raw if this contains user-generated content, even a user name, because of HTML injection risk

Comment: yeah the quotes not being there are a typo. The output consists of various combinations with most characters unescaped or escaped in different ways which I am trying to avoid. The security risk I already understand.

Comment: So you want the page source to include the special characters like `\n` / `\t` as text and not as actual line breaks / tabs?

Comment: Although I'm also curious how to do this, I also wonder if there's a legit reason you need to do it

Comment: Just realized keeping spaces and tabs is completely useless and doesn't serve my goal. Yet am still curious of the solution, since something similar happens when escaping regexps, and other sensitive strings when passing them from js to ruby.

Comment: Answer to your question is yes.